# How to dismiss Java security warning

Tags: java, security, ssl, applet

How to avoid this message on Windows XP, please?

I have tried to create the exception for my domain (with trusted SSL certificate) in Java settings, put all the security levels to the lovest values but this warning still occurs.

It is really annoying when I have to click on this 3 times a minute (Zebra printer printing applet).

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Trusted SSL certificate' is irrelevant. You need to sign the applet with a trusted *signing* certificate.

Comment: It have been signed too, but the problem was that we needed some custom build of the applet for Windows XP as the problem occured just on WXP. Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific about that? What was the actual issue, and what was custom about the build?